# Where did the energy of the charge go?

Tags: special-relativity, collision, radioactivity

Suppose there is a positron and an electron, and they both collide, and we get $E=2mc^2$ of energy from the collision. Now, the charge also got vanished. Now suppose, I create neutrinos from the collision's energy, which are neutral and that doesn't violate conservation of charge, now the mass-energy of the neutrinos is same as the mass energy of the positron and electron destroyed.

But instead if I make electron and positron pair again from that energy, it doesn't violate conservation of charge either, but this implies that creating one kind of charge requires positive energy and creating the other requires negative energy in some form. Isn't it ?

Comment: I don't think you will get the answer until physics finds out what charge really is and how the related forces work (i.e. how a "minus" makes a "plus" move - or the other way round).

Comment: Explain *negative* and *positive* energy...

Answer (score 2):

Any energy tied up in the charges is already factored into the mass of the particles.  Conservation of energy doesn't care whether I create $E$ worth of charged particles or $E$ worth of neutral particles, so long as my other conservation laws are obeyed.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose there is a positron and an electron, and they both collide, and we get E=2mc2 of energy from the collision.

Only in the center of mass system of the two, electron positron. It depends on the frame one is working. In the lab frame  the positron will have  E=mc**2 but the electron will have only its rest mass, m_0.

> Now, the charge also got vanished. Now suppose, I create neutrinos from the collision's energy, which are neutral and that doesn't violate conservation of charge,

so far so good.

> now the mass-energy of the neutrinos is same as the mass energy of the positron and electron destroyed.

No, the neutrinos have very much smaller rest mass than the individual electron/positron and their four vectors will not be the same as the four vector of the electron/positron. Total energy and momentum are conserved.

> But instead if I make electron and positron pair again from that energy,

it is called [Bhabha scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhabha_scattering)

> it doesn't violate conservation of charge either,

right,

> but this implies that creating one kind of charge requires positive energy and creating the other requires negative energy in some form. Isn't it ?

No there are no negative energies involved. Momentum and energy are conserved in this quite usual reaction.  Electron positrons do not have to annihilate when scattering, there is a probability that they may, but also a probability of scattering elastically.